# Prevent a file/folder being invisible

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, file-attributes

Is there a way to prevent a file or folder being set invisible ? I am working on an infected machine (which I cannot disinfect) that constantly makes the files and folders in my usb stick invisible. I use the:

`attrib -h -r -s /s /d f:\*.*`

command to make them visible again but the problem continues since this command just saves the day.

Comment: "(which I cannot disinfect)" ... why? Sounds like that should be your first priority.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes but I have no control on the machine for doing that

Comment: I certainly wouldn't put that USB back in any other machine afterwards - bin it.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you to disinfect your machine. Try to download and install an antivirus soon. It must be the best solution.

If you still want to prevent your files/folders from getting invisible without any antivirus, you can write protect your usb via the windows registry option. It will deny access for the malware that makes the invisibility issue. I'll help you write protect your usb here.

### Write protecting usb via windows registry editor...

- open the run window using win key + r.
- type **regedit** and hit enter to open the registry editor window.
- look for **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** on the left pane and enter into it
- look for **System** and get into it
- look for **CurrentControlSet** and get into it
- look for **Control** and right click on it
- **New -> Key** to create a new folder inside **Control**
- rename the folder as **StorageDevicePolicies**
- right click on **StorageDevicePolicies**
- **New -> DWORD(32-bit) Value** to create a new REG_DWORD on the right pane
- rename the new REG_DWORD on the right pane to **WriteProtect**
- right click on **WriteProtect** and choose **Modify** to open the Edit D-WORD window
- in the opened window, look for **Value data** and change it to 1
- close the registry editor window

Thats it. You are done. The malware access into your pendrive will be denied. So, no hide and seeks now :)